# How to find which app is running a TOR inside my server

Tags: amazon-web-services, tor

I really hope someone can help.
I have a tor running inside one of my servers (reported by AWS guard) and I have no idea how can I trace it to which application is running the tor socket?

attached is the report from aws so I can see the IP and port

[image]

[image]

any assistance is appreciated

Comment: That is incoming traffic to your port 80.  Its not in your server. Its a Tor proxy. That report is an INBOUND traffic event.

Comment: thank you for the reply... I appreciate it very much. So what are you saying? That TOR is trying to access my Apache server on port 80? Any info you can share would be GREATLY appreciated!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Sure.  Yes its an inbound tor proxy. You have a web service on that instance?  A Tor user went to your site via  Tor. Its a little odd traffic pattern  but GuardDuty is just warning you. Its show the Severity as Medium

Comment: thank you. Let me tell you my setup, in port 80 I run Apache server and in another interface I also use port 80 for node.js server. So what should I do next? So the tor proxy is talking to my port 80? is that something to worry about? What should I do next? any netstate ? commands to run to find out more? Just want to make sure the server is not compromised :(   tx again!!!

Comment: I would not worry about it. Its random traffic I think. Check your www logs see what its looking for. Block the IP if you like. PS This is off topic for SO - you should try on SeverFault for more help.  If your site is open to the public, you will get odd traffic sometimes checking for vulnerabilities. Just make sure you are secure and its fine. Probably some french script kiddie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your website is public, expose it to internet through AWS CloudFront. Also you can put it behind AWS WAF. This is the best way to secure your website, leave the heavy lifting to AWS and you can focus on your own business functional requirements.

Besides security, using AWS CloudFront has other advantages, such as protection against DDoS attacks, lower latency for end-users and lower prices, as most requests can get responses out of CloudFront edge cache and don't need to travel all the way to your origin servers.

In summary, consider changing your architecture to include following:

1. AWS CloudFront
2. AWS WAF
3. AWS Shield